# Errors trying to run gnattest

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm trying to run gnattest on a Ada project file:

```
gnattest -P(projectname)
```

and I get the following errors:

> object path not found for runtime native
> gnattest: initialization failed

I made sure the gnatpro-v20.2/bin directory was part of the path.  I tried adding other gnat directories to the path.  I tried running the command inside of GPS and from command line.

Comment: You might look in `share/examples/gnattest`; e.g. `pushd simple/` followed by `gnattest -P simple.gpr`.

Comment: it gave me a new error.  'default.gpr:1:06: unknown project file: "aunit"'

Comment: I can't reproduce this using the tutorial in `README.Testing`.

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out. The fact that running the sample gave me a different error inspired me to try creating a new, from scratch, gpr just for the unit testing. The project I was using before had a bunch of conditions in it and a main. I created a simple gpr, based on the sample, that didn't have a main.

At my company, when IT installs a product they do so on their accounts, so the environment for the users is not always updated . During my research I found there is a file called aunit.gpr that is in the share/gpr folder. I created a variable called GPR_PROJECT_PATH that pointed at that folder. This seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had these same errors, and they were caused by the presence of a GNAT toolchain in my `PATH` ahead of the path that includes `gnattest`. The system GCC or user GCC/GNAT installations usually do not include the necessary support libraries to be compatible with `gnattest` by default, as GNATtest is now limited to the GNAT Pro suite.

Run the command `gnatls -v` to see the active GNAT search paths. Ensure that these match the install path (e.g. `/usr/local/gnatpro-vXX.Y/bin`) for the `gnattest` binary you are using. On Linux, `which gnattest` will tell you the path or alias being executed for `gnattest`.

**NOTE:** To use the FSF GNAT build tools with GNATtest, you would need to install the AUnit library and any other supporting libraries in the correct search paths for that version of GNAT.